# Reaver hanged up on waiting for beacon

Tags: linux, wifi

These are the commands I put into the terminal on my laptop.

`root@ubuntu:~#   reaver -i mon0 -b F8:7B:7A:69:9F`

```
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
```

`Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>`

```
[+] Waiting for beacon from F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F

root@ubuntu:~#
```

This is what it says after brute forcing it

F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F         -43        7        0    0   6  54   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  p

Edit: It's been almost 5 years since this question was asked.

### Question

What causes  Reaver to be hanged up on beacon? Could it be a software problem with Linux itself? Can it be the security used in the network? What is it?

Comment: Try using `reaver -i mon0 -b F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F -vv` to get verbose output maybe then you'll get an idea of the problem

Comment: It switching channels on mon0

Comment: Should, I change the capitalized letters to lowercase or would that target a different bssid?

Comment: The best I can figure is the mac address is wrong.  You have 5 slots when there normally is 6 for example `DE:AD:BE:EF:CO:FE` try using `airodump-ng wlan0` or `airodump-ng mon0` again and copy the full address.

Comment: I wouldn't change it to lowercase it may or may not be case sensitive

Comment: Also you could try using `aircrack-ng` as an alternative to reaver.

Comment: Will it use bruteforce or would I need to make a wordlist?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site http://superuser.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever come up with a solution to this problem ?

Comment: I found [this blog post](https://kakkulearning.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/hack-wpawpa2-wps-reaver-kali-linux/), but it didn't helped me unfortunately. I post it anyway as it might work for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could set the channel `reaver -i mon0 -b F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F -c <channel> -vv` might work a little better at least it will be more targeted.

Comment: which i would assume is channel 6

Comment: If that's what `airodump-ng` said.

Comment: Well its not going to work on all networks just means your router has good security.

Comment: Reaver appears to be hanging up what now? This is what it says [+] Waiting for beacon from F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F

Comment: Its my hotspot on my cellphone that I'm testing.

Comment: I'll come back after I read the tutorial on aircrack-ng. I have it installed on my laptop I just need to learn how to use it to test my hotspot on my cellphone to see if it is possible to crack my cellphone hotspot.

Comment: This popped up [!] WARNING: Failed to associate with F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F (ESSID: p)